# ARM setup cache and mmu from armasm to gnu arm assembler

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi, gnu, fasm

I'm trying to run a bare metal program on raspberry pi 2. I want to setup cache and mmu, and I refer to [arm documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0425/ch04s01s01.html).

First, I use FASMARM assembler to compile my code. It's can run on raspberry pi 2 successfully.

```
    @;enable cache
    @;Enables coherent requests to the processor
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
    ORR r1, r1, 0x40
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Disable MMU
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    BIC r1, r1, #0x1
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Disable L1 Caches
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    BIC r1, r1, 0x1000
    BIC r1, r1, 0x4
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Invalidate Instruction cache
    MOV r1, #0
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c7, c5, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Invalidate Data cache
    MRC p15, 1, r0, c0, c0, 0
    MOV r3, 0x1ff
    AND r0, r3, r0, LSR #13
    MOV r1, #0
way_loop:
    MOV r3, #0
set_loop:
    MOV r2, r1, LSL #30
    ORR r2, r2, r3, LSL #5
    MCR p15, 0, r2, c7, c6, 2
    ADD r3, r3, #1
    CMP r0, r3
    BGE set_loop
    ADD r1, r1, #1
    CMP r1, #4
    BNE way_loop
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Invalidate TLB
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c8, c7, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Branch Prediction Enable
    MOV r1, #0
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    ORR r1, r1, 0x800
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    DSB

    ;@ Enable L1 Data prefetch control
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
    ORR r1, r1, 0x6000
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Initialize PageTable
    MOV r0, 0xde2
    MOV r1, 0x00004000
    MOV r3, 0
    ORR r2, r0, r3, LSL #20
    STR r2, [r1]
    BIC r0, r0, 0xc
    ORR r0, r0, 0x4
    BIC r0, r0, 0x7000
    ORR r0, r0, 0x5000
    ORR r0, r0, 0x10000
    STR r0, [r1]
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Initialize MMU
    MOV r1, 0x0
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c2, c0, 2
    MOV r1, 0x00004000
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c2, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Set all Domains to Client
    mov r1, 0x5555
    movt r1, 0x5555
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c3, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Enable MMU
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    ORR r1, r1, 0x1
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Enable cache
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    ORR r1, r1, 0x4
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

    ;@ Enable I cache
    MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    ORR r1, r1, 0x1000
    MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    DSB
    ISB

   @; end enable cache
```

I need to transform the code to the form that can be compiled by GNU assembler. However, the code below cannot work on raspberry pi 2.

```
    @; enable cache
    @; Enables coherent requests to the processor
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
     orr r1, r1, #0x40
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
     DSB
     ISB

    ;@ Disable MMU
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     BIC r1, r1, #0x1
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB
     ;@ Disable L1 Caches
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     BIC r1, r1, #0x1000
     BIC r1, r1, #0x4 
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     DSB  
     ISB

     ;@ Invalidate Instruction cache
     MOV r1, #0
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c7, c5, 0
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Invalidate Data cache
     MRC p15, 1, r0, c0, c0, 0
     LDR r3, =#0x1ff
     AND r0, r3, r0, LSR #13
     MOV r1, #0
 way_loop:
     MOV r3, #0
 set_loop:
     MOV r2, r1, LSL #30
     ORR r2, r2, r3, LSL #5
     MCR p15, 0, r2, c7, c6, 2
     ADD r3, r3, #1
     CMP r0, r3
     BGE set_loop
     ADD r1, r1, #1
     CMP r1, #4
     BNE way_loop
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Invalidate TLB
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c8, c7, 0
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Branch Prediction Enable
     MOV r1, #0
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     ORR r1, r1, #0x800
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB

    ;@ Enable L1 Data prefetch control
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
     ORR r1, r1, #0x6000
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 1
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Initialize PageTable
     LDR r0, =#0xde2
     MOV r1, #0x00004000
     MOV r3, #0
     ORR r2, r0, r3, LSL #20
     STR r2, [r1]
     BIC r0, r0, #0xc
     ORR r0, r0, #0x4
     BIC r0, r0, #0x7000
     ORR r0, r0, #0x5000
     ORR r0, r0, #0x10000
     STR r0, [r1]
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Initialize MMU
     MOV r1, #0x0
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c2, c0, 2
     MOV r1, #0x00004000
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c2, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Set all Domains to Client
     LDR r1, =#0x5555
     movt r1, #0x5555
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c3, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB
     ;@ Enable MMU
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     ORR r1, r1, #0x1
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB

    ;@ Enable cache
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     ORR r1, r1, #0x4
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB

     ;@ Enable I cache
     MRC p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     ORR r1, r1, #0x1000
     MCR p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
     DSB
     ISB
```

I'm not sure whether the problem occurs in enabling mmu, because the code can work if I comment out the section of enable mmu.

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that looks to make a possible difference there is the use of literal loads - since the assembler just dumps the literal pool at the end of the file, execution runs the risk of running straight into the data:

```
...
 154:   e3811a01        orr     r1, r1, #4096   ; 0x1000
 158:   ee011f10        mcr     15, 0, r1, cr1, cr0, {0}
 15c:   f57ff04f        dsb     sy
 160:   f57ff06f        isb     sy
 164:   000001ff        .word   0x000001ff
 168:   00000de2        .word   0x00000de2
 16c:   00005555        .word   0x00005555
```

For those cases, it would be better to convert the `mov` to an explicit `movw`, rather than `ldr=`, to avoid the literals entirely - GAS is apparently too stupid to realise that the unified syntax expects `mov` with a 16-bit immediate to automatically select the `movw` encoding; I guess FASMARM is doing that correctly.

Comment: I don't think the GNU Assembler uses the unified syntax by default.

Comment: @Ross indeed (although its 'ARM syntax' parsing is so lax it still accepts most of UAL), but even `.syntax unified; mov r0, #0x5555` with `-march=armv7-a` still errors out with "invalid constant (5555) after fixup" - I did check!